# How to match exact string using `sed`? But not the part of it.?

Tags: sed, string, patterns

I have a input file **FILE1.TXT** as below.

---

```
11 id1  
12  
13 AGE = 20  
14 NAME = NAME1  
15  
16 id2  
17  
18 AGE = 30  
19 NAME = NAME2  
.  
.  
.  
110 idXYZ  
111  
112 AGE = AGEXYZ  
113 NAME = NAMEXYZ  
114  
115 idZZZ  
116
```

---

I want to search all the fields that belong to a particular *Id* and get the value for *NAME*

I managed to loop through each *Id* and formed the below command for each *Id* as required.

`sed -n '/11/,/14/p' FILE1.TXT | grep NAME | awk -F "= " '{print $2}'`

The problem here is, I get the output *NAME1*, in addition to that, I also get *NAMEXYZ*.

What should be changed so that I only get *NAME1* but not *NAMEXYZ*?

As a workaround, the below commands work.

`sed -n '/11/,/14/p' FILE1.TXT | grep NAME | awk -F "= " '{print $2}'|head -1`

Is there any 'switch' or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the line numbers you want to search (as your Q suggests), tighten the regex so that you don't match unwanted lines.

For example, change:

```
sed -n '/11/,/14/p' | grep NAME | awk -F "= " '{print $2}'
```

to

```
sed -n '/^11 /,/^14 /p' | grep NAME | awk -F "= " '{print $2}'
```

The `^` will match the beginning of the line and a space after the number guarantees that the specific line number will be matched, and you won't process unwanted blocks.

Comment: That would help. But, How can I match `^(random no of spaces)11` ?

Comment: @VinayChalluru use `sed -n '/^\s*11 /,/^\s*14 /p'`

Comment: it can be short hand using `sed -n '/^11 /,/^14 /p' | awk '/NAME/{print $NF}'`  have you tried this ?

Comment: @RahulPatil Yes, It works.

Answer (score 6):

Use word boundaries:

```
grep '\bNAME1\b'
```

would match `NAME1` and not `NAME1XYZ` or `XYZNAME1`.

Similarly,

```
sed -n '/11\b/,/14\b/p'
```

wouldn't match lines containing `111` and `142`.

---

EDIT: It seems that the numbers in the input file are actually line numbers.  If that is the case, you could simply say:

```
sed '11,14!d'
```

to get the desired lines.

Comment: There is only one `NAME` between the lines 11 and 14. So, why is `sed` looking at `111` and `114`? How to make it not look in between `111` and `114`?

Comment: @VinayChalluru See the answer above for how you could modify the `sed` expression.

Comment: This answers my question I guess. Let me try and let you know.

Comment: for word boundaries , `grep` with `-w` flag ? isn't it ?

Comment: @RahulPatil Yup, for the above example `-w` would be equivalent.  For the `sed` example, `-w` is slightly different.

Comment: @RahulPatil At times, it's tough to figure the question.  I updated the answer with an option to suit what the _OP probably wanted_.

Comment: @devnull Thanks for the edit. This might help me next time. But, the numbers are not the line numbers but part of input file.

Comment: @VinayChalluru If line numbers aren't part of your input then what made you say _That would save me lot of code lines._ for the `awk` answer.

Comment: This is not the exact input file and not exactly what I'm doing. I gave a sample with just two fields. Btw, I'll try to do it based on the line numbers in file too. Let me try.

Answer (score 4):

You can use AWK

```
awk 'NR>=13 && NR<=17 && /NAME/{print $NF}' infile
```

This will look lines between 13 to 17 then search for Name and if match then it will print last word from `Name = LastWord`

Comment: When I try to do this, I get an error saying that the input line number must be less than 199.

Comment: @VinayChalluru can you show me output with command, use http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Apologies. I added an `$` before `NR` and that caused the error.

Comment: @VinayChalluru It's OK. that's Good you tried/tested each ans and learn something new.. :D

Comment: Exactly. There's a lot more ahead. :-)

Comment: What am I supposed to use to print first word from `Word = Name` instead of $NF?

Comment: @VinayChalluru line is split(default white space separator) into fields, so you can access each of field like `$1`, So input line :`Name = LastWord` `{ print $1,$3}` will print Name and LastWord

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I knew about using `$1`. Earlier didn't know about `$NF` and I thought, I'm missing something else, hence asked.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any other tool for this, `sed` will easily handle it entire.

```
sed -nr '/11/,/14/{s/^.*NAME =\s*(\S*).*$/\1/p}' <$infile
```

That should provide you only with the first sequence of non-whitespace characters following the phrase "NAME = " for every line on which that phrase is found between lines 11 and 14 of any input file `sed` is fed.

Answer (score 3):

sed is not the right tool for this job. Use awk where you can specify the id you're looking for and print the next NAME that appears.

```
awk -v id="id2" '
    $NF == id {have_id = 1} 
    have_id && $0 ~ /NAME/ {print $NF; exit}
' filename
```

Comment: Could you explain line two and three of your awk command?

Answer (score 1):

you can print those lines which contain matching pattern using sed as follows:

```
sed -n '/pattern/p'  Filename
```

- `-n` - these options disable this automatic printing, and sed only
   produces output when explicitly told to via the `p` command.
- `p` - print

Answer (score 0):

generic version not based on line number but id reference

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;
$ {
  x
  s/.*/&\^J/
: clean
#  put your ID pattern here in place of id9
  s/.*\(id9 *\n.*\)id[0-9]\{1,\} *\n.*/\1/
  t clean
  s/.*NAME = \([^[:cntrl:]]*\)\n.*/\1/
  p
  }' YourFile
```

1. load the whole file
2. clean section not part of the id group (recursive)
3. just take NAME content value in the group
4. print the result