# Match EXACT string in file and update IP Address

Tags: sed, scripting, ip

There two steps, first check if exist the host in the file

If have the file:

```
# FILE: /etc/hosts:
192.168.0.10 srv-db srv-db-home
192.168.0.15 srv-db1
192.168.0.20 srv-db-2
192.168.0.20 srv-db-work srv-db-
```

Would execute:

```
sed -n -e '/\<srv-db\>/p' /etc/hosts
```

Which results to:

```
192.168.0.10 srv-db
192.168.0.20 srv-db-2
192.168.0.20 srv-db-
```

It ignores the number at the end just fine... but it does not ignore the dash (**-**).

I have found a bunch of regex that works parcially... as these two below:

[Match exact string using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206903/match-exact-string-using-grep)

and

[How to match exact string using `sed`? But not the part of it.?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117956/how-to-match-exact-string-using-sed-but-not-the-part-of-it)

The answer below from @steeldriver helped with that:

```
awk '$NF == "srv-db"' /etc/hosts
```

But, when going to update the IP Address, it becames fuzzy, here is the full code I have camed up with:

```
sed -i -e "s/\(^ *[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\(\s*\)\<srv-db\>/192.168.9.9\2/" /etc/hosts
```

It should update only the first line, but instead it updates the same results as of above.

But none of them has worked perfectly is this particular case.

Comment: _But none of them has worked perfectly is this particular case._ - why not?

Comment: because of the dash...(**-**) at the end of the string inside of the file.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the _complete_ command that you used and what the result was. This gives "us" something tangible to chew on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\>` word boundary anchor treats `-` as a boundary.

If you know that there is no trailing whitespace, you could anchor to the end of line `/\<srv-db$/` - to allow for trailing whitespace you could modify that to `/\<srv-db[[:blank:]]*$/` or `/\<srv-db[[:space:]]*$/`

Or use `awk` and do a *string* match instead:

```
awk '$NF == "srv-db"' /etc/hosts
```

---

If you can't necessarily anchor to the end of line (even with trailing whitespace) then you will beed to construct an expression that (for example) tests for whitespace or end of line (i.e. "word boundary without hyphen") e.g. (using *extended regular expression* mode)

```
sed -En -e '/\<srv-db(\s|$)/p'
```

If you can use perl (or grep in PCRE mode) then there are possibly more elegant options such as

```
perl -ne 'print if /\bsrv-db(?![\w-])/'
```

or

```
grep -P '\bsrv-db(?![\w-])'
```

Comment: When substituing with my formula as of below, it is not working, could you take a look at: `sed -i -e "s/\(^ *[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\(\s*\)\<srv-db([[:blank:]]|$)/192.168.9.9\2/" /etc/hosts`

Comment: If I take **-E** which I have never seen it and could not find in the docs... it will not even bring us the result as expected.

Comment: If you're **not** using `-E` (extended regex) as indicated by your escaping of the braces, then the 'or' operator `|` must also be escaped, I think. You need to choose either BRE or ERE mode and stick with it.

Comment: Working: ` sed -E -e "s/(^ *[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3})(\s\*)(\<srv-db(\s|$))/192.168.200.254\2\3/" /etc/hosts` Thanks you very much!